# How to approach API testing?

Tags: api, rest

This is one of the most common needs today and consequently a common interview question.

This question is intended to be a canonical answer to the general question of "How do I test an API".  Other questions in this vein are more specific.  For this question I am going high-level as indicated by the short question title.

Comment: Do you mean remote API? Or API of a class, of a library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### API Test Checklist

> - Endpoints
> - Actions
> - Status Codes
> - Payload Data
> - Performance
> - Security

#### Specifically

- Verbs / Actions / Methods
- What documentation exists ?
- What functionality it provide ?
- Does it support concurrency ?
- What are the API endpoints ?
- Is the API internal or external ?
- Which endpoints are idempotent ?
- Are endpoints stateless or stateful ?
- Do any workflows<sup>1</sup> vary by client ?
- Are there performance requirements ?
- Do API endpoints make up a workflow ?
- What validations are expected for data ?
- What system or library is behind the API ?
- Do we need to mock dependent services ?
- Does it constrain traffic aka [Rate Limiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting) ?
- Is the API restricted to a country or region ?
- What (if any) versioning approach is used ?
- Does the API support Multiple Languages ?
- If already using [SOAPui](https://www.soapui.org/), how is it integrated ?
- Does it provide client stubs in specific languages ?
- What status codes are expected for given endpoints ?
- Does the API use HATEOS<sup>2</sup> for self documentation ?
- What kind of data validation/ testing can be performed ?
- What API is supported by the test framework I'm using ?
- What actions are performed, e.g. GET, PUT, POST etc ?
- Do we need to prepare dependent test data or services ?
- What non-API approaches will be needed to verify data ?
- What non-API approaches will be needed to prepare data ?
- Are there existing API definitions e.g. [WADL](https://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/), [WSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/NOTE-wsdl-20010315), [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) ?
- What (if any) Authorization (‘what’) mechanism will be used ?
- What (if any) Authentication (‘who’) mechanism will be used ?
- Who will use it, external programmers or another internal module ?
- What format(s): [SOAP](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap/), [REST](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/REST), [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/), [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/), [ProtoBuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers), Other ?

#### Practically

Here are some more specific things to check in a HTTP based API:

- Can I change the ID in a put call ?
- Can I PUT an object with an invalid ID ?
- Can I POST an object with an existing ID ?
- Can I GET an object I am not authorized to get ?
- Can I PUT an object that I am not authorized for ?
- Can I GET an object I am not authenticated to get ?
- Does deleting require Authentication / Authorization ?
- Can I POST an object that I am not authenticated for ?
- Can I access hidden information without authorization ?
- Can an attacker determined which resources routes exist by 401 vs 404 ?
- Can I search for information that I am not allowed to see available directly through a route ?
- Does deleting a parent or (only 1) referenced record delete the associated record as expected ?

---

<sup>1</sup> Workflows often require multiple API calls and may have dependencies between them
<sup>2</sup> HATEOS - Hypertext As The Engine Of Application State, which allows self-discovery of an API.
Also known as Hypermedia.

Comment: A very interesting overview, and today one of the most important questions at all. But you wouldn't have to clarify which tools make a test possible via an API gateway. Let's take the example of WSO2 which has already integrated load and performance testing, penetration.

Comment: Another point would be the direct integration of SoapUI into existing environments.

Comment: @Mornon thanks i added that

Comment: Another point that should be examined accordingly. If the API is possibly tested via an external pipeline, SoapUI can also be executed in a Jenkins pipeline. Here the question arises, if I used an API gateway, is the pipeline integrated into the gateway and is an existing or even a new API tested via it?

Comment: Meta: Can one answer their own question?

Comment: @michael I think that one should perhaps first define the point of the analysis itself when asking all the questions. If an existing system already exists, how do I get this changed so that the APIs there can be tested on a new environment?

Comment: Does it constrain traffic aka Ratę Limiting? Does it provide client stubs in specific languages or IDL to generate such clients e.g. WADL, WSDL, Thrift definitions?

Comment: I would add GraphQL, Thrift and ProtoBuffer to the list of message formats. Dont forget about RMI and CORBA. Plus libraries like DDL or Python packages also have APIs unless you mean only remote API (RPC)? That should be clarified in the question.

Comment: Is the API stateless or stateful? Idempotent or not?

Comment: What system or library is behind the API? What functionality it provide?

Comment: Does it support concurrency?

Comment: Who Will be using it? External programmers or other internal module? That defines usability readibility requirements.

Comment: We're up to 32 points now thanks to all.  Our interviewer is probably exhausted ;)

Comment: WADL and WSDL are API DEFINITIONS not clients.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Another point would be which test automation I used, because where are starting points for Selenium. SoapUI supports Selenium among other things.

Comment: In addition to Selenium, there are other integrations of SoapUI with Serenity, among others. We should also define which further integrations are necessary for testing.

How to generate Maven SoapUI Serenity reports

Thank you for your post! Please refer to the following links:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thucydides-users/waJkpiLgVYQ

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972008/generate-serenity-aggregate-report-when-tests-are-execu...

Comment: An interesting approach might be the point, which test frameworks based on BDD could be integrated. SoapUI offers for example the integration into Cucumber. @MichaelDurrant http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2011/11/16/testing-a-web-service-with-soapui-junit-maven-and-cucumber

Comment: @JoãoFarias - One can absolutely answer their own question. It's most common for canonical questions/answer like this one, but can also happen when someone has a problem and later finds the answer and posts it for reference (like this question: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3645/testcomplete-working-with-a-very-large-application-loses-the-ability-to-access-a)

Comment: Yeah, the second case I knew - good to know about the first one :D